# Set index values for python plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am graphing three lines on a single plot. I want the x-axis to display the date the data was taken on and the time from 00:00 to 24:00. Right now my code displays the time of day correctly but for the date, instead of the date that the data was recorded on being displayed, the current date is shown (12-18). I am unsure how to correct this. Also it would be acceptable for my plot to show only time from 00:00 to 24:00 with out the date on the x-axis. Thank you for your help!!

```
# set index as time for graphing
monAverages['Time'] = monAverages['Time'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(str(x)))
index = monAverages['Time']
index = index.apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(str(x)))
averagePlot = dfSingleDay
predictPlot = predictPlot[np.isfinite(predictPlot)]
datasetPlot = datasetPlot[np.isfinite(datasetPlot)]
predictPlot1 = pd.DataFrame(predictPlot)
datasetPlot1 = pd.DataFrame(datasetPlot)
averagePlot.set_index(index, drop=True,inplace=True)
datasetPlot1.set_index(index, drop=True,inplace=True)
predictPlot1.set_index(index, drop=True,inplace=True)
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (10,10)
plt.plot(datasetPlot1,'b', label='Real Data')
plt.plot(averagePlot, 'y', label='Average for this day of the week')
plt.plot(predictPlot1, 'g', label='Predictions')
plt.title('Power Consumption')
plt.xlabel('Date (00-00) and Time of Day(00)')
plt.ylabel('kW')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be sure that you get only the time:

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
# set index as time for graphing
monAverages['Time'] = monAverages['Time'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(str(x)))
index = monAverages['Time']
#index = index.apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(str(x)))
dates= [dt.datetime.strptime(d,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').time() for d in index]
averagePlot = dfSingleDay
predictPlot = predictPlot[np.isfinite(predictPlot)]
datasetPlot = datasetPlot[np.isfinite(datasetPlot)]
predictPlot1 = pd.DataFrame(predictPlot)
datasetPlot1 = pd.DataFrame(datasetPlot)

plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (10,10)
plt.plot(dates,datasetPlot1,'b', label='Real Data')
plt.plot(dates,averagePlot, 'y', label='Average for this day of the week')
plt.plot(dates,predictPlot1, 'g', label='Predictions')
plt.title('Power Consumption')
plt.xlabel('Date (00-00) and Time of Day(00)')
plt.ylabel('kW')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

This code here explains how you can run it

```
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
dates = ['2019-12-18 00:00:00','2019-12-18 12:00:00','2019-12-18 13:00:00']
x = [dt.datetime.strptime(d,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').time() for d in dates]
y = range(len(x))


plt.plot(x,y)
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I am unsure where to insert this into my code, and what I need to remove from my code to make it work. Currently I used your first approach and added it under the line "    datasetPlot1 = pd.DataFrame(datasetPlot) ". When I do this I get the error " module 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'dates' "

Comment: You can try it now.

Comment: I used the first block of code and got the error " Timestamp' object is not subscriptable ". Thank you for your time and help!!

Comment: When I use the second block of code, I get an error " module 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'xaxis' ". Thank you for your time and help!!

Comment: I apologize, not sure how I can show the index values, because the plot will not display anymore because of the error, and all of the code is in a plot function I created so I can't access the variables outside of the function. I am using jupyter notebook if that helps.

Comment: @the_dankest try the second pert.

Comment: I ran the second block of code, and got the error "TypeError: object of type 'DateFormatter' has no len()". There is also this before the error message " SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead ". Thank you so much for your time and help!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204518/discussion-between-i-th-and-the-dankest).